# How to change "Favourites" and "Recently Visited" icons in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, icon, bookmarks

My homepage in Safari is the default one, the one that shows Favourite and Recently visited files. However, when I opened Safari today the icons were bigger than they were previously. Is it possible to set a smaller size again?

This is what I get.[image]

It is even clearer in this situation:
[image]

Usually, the icons you see in the two images were smaller, and in the second one in particular the six favourite pages could fit all in one line.

Comment: Try Cmd - [minus]

Comment: Already tried, but that doesn't work

Comment: It's usually helpful to include what you already tried in your question. It saves duplicated effort.

Comment: Perhaps Safari 13 has been installed and the change is related to that occurrence?